# How to put a Custom Folder under one sub-site of Multisite WP?

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, urls, directory

I have a multisite wordpress and i'm now trying to have a custom directory under 1 of the sites of the multisite. Example:

```
http://apple.example.com
http://banana.example.com/myfolder
http://candy.example.com
```

That means `/myfolder` should not be available under `apple` and `candy` but just under `banana` site.

But it is totally **non-wordpress** related folder and will be totally different web folder, having another html contents. Can assume as **a small html website**.

- How to allow my custom uploaded folder `/myfolder` to be available **only under** the one specific sub-site (under multisite)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it mean, you want to save the uploaded contents of the site `http://banana.example.com` in `my-folder` instead of the respective uploaded folder for that sub site.

Comment: NO. That folder might be for anything. Anything even lets say an example, the `DRUPAL` install there? Ya, may be. Anything totally out of WP.